# Hooks cannot be defined inside tests. Hook of type "beforeEach" is nested within "TestName"

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a service that I would like to test, let's call it serviceA.

```
export class ServiceA {

constructor(protected serviceB: ServiceB) {}
//some more code here
```

serviceA depends on serviceB.

serviceB depends on ServiceC.

serviceC also depends on some injected token.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class serviceC {
    constructor(@Inject(SYSTEM_NAME) private systemName:string) {}

//more code here
```

to test serviceA, I created 2 service factories:
one for serviceC (that serviceB depends on)
and one for ServiceA.

everything works fine, but when I call `createServiceA(serviceB)` I'm getting an error:

**Error: Hooks cannot be defined inside tests. Hook of type "beforeEach" is nested within "should create an instance".**

```
let spectatorServiceC: SpectatorService<ServiceC>;
let spectatorServiceA: SpectatorService<ServiceA>;
let serviceB: ServiceB;

describe('ServiceA', () => {
    
    const createServiceC = createServiceFactory({
        service: ServiceC,
        providers: [
            { provide: SYSTEM_NAME, useValue: SYSTEM_NAME_VALUE }
        ],
    });

    const createServiceA = (serviceB: ServiceB) => createServiceFactory({
        service: ServiceA,
        providers: [
            { provide: ServiceB, useValue: serviceB },
            ServiceC
        ],
    }) as any;


  beforeEach(() => {
        spectatorServiceC = createServiceC();
        serviceB = new ServiceB(spectatorServiceC.service);

        spectatorServiceA = createServiceA(serviceB); //error happens by adding it
  });
    
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    expect(serviceB.service).toBeTruthy();
  });
```